# Normal Xcode Application Memory Usage

Tags: swift, xcode, memory

I've been getting a lot of warnings about running out of application memory on my mac recently, so I have started paying closer attention to my activity monitor.

[image]

[image]

This seems bad. What can I do about this? For context, my xcode project contains about twenty swift files. So it's large, but not impossibly so. And I'm not doing anything super complex--just pulling a couple of json files from a local server and fetching and caching 5-10 images from firebase.

Another question--is it simply an xcode problem or is there something in my code that is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be memory leak.
You should try to diagnose memory leaks using Instruments.

I found these steps [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/diagnose-memory-leaks-using-xcode-instruments-5692a6458020):

**•** Choose “Xcode” in the top left of the screen

**•** Expand “Open Developer Tool,” and select “Instruments”

**•** Now choose “Leaks,” and make sure you have chosen your target app and device at the top (“Choose a profiling template for…”)

**•** Finally, press the record button